# Print output and errors without '[b', \r, \n, ]'. How can I do that?

Tags: python

I'm using python version 3.10.10 and trying to make this little program to show errors of a python code otherwise it will print the output. But When I run it, it show all the thing such as this,

```
[b'  File "C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpi7zvvi52", line 2\r\n', b"
    print('hello)\r\n", b' 
    ^\r\n', b'
    SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 2)\r\n']
```

Here it shows the error with these,
`b'`, `\r\n']`, `\r\n', b`.

So how can I print only the errors and the output without those?

Here is my code,

```
import tempfile, os, sys, subprocess

# code
code = '''
print('hello)
'''

# save the code to a temporary file
file_handle, file_path = tempfile.mkstemp()
tmp_file = os.fdopen(file_handle, 'w')
tmp_file.write(code)
tmp_file.close()

#execute it
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, file_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# wait for the command to complete 
p.wait()

# retrieve the output:
pyerr = p.stderr.readlines()
pyout = p.stdout.readlines()

if pyerr:
    print(pyerr)
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print(pyout)
```

Comment: `readlines` is returning a list of strings so you'll want to either join them into one or print each string individually

Comment: Currently it's returning byte arrays rather than strings. You could call `.decode()` on them, or you could specify `text=True` when calling `Popen`, in order to get strings.